# Recently downloaded WordPress 5.7.2 but when run on localhost fetch error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, wordpress-5

I download WordPress 5.7.2 zip file on official site. after extract file and put it on htdocs and run it on browser localhost/wordpress/index.php.
But fetch error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE
> in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1090

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to [their website](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/): To run WordPress you need to have the following:

- PHP 7.4 or greater
- MySQL 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB 10.1 or greater
- Nginx or Apache with mod_rewrite module HTTPS support

---

### Check your PHP version :

1. Make a file called `phpinfo.php` in the `htdocs` folder
2. Only put this inside it :

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

1. Save
2. Go to http://localhost/phpinfo.php

⚠ If your PHP version is below 7.4,
you are likely getting this error because of that. You need to [update your PHP version](https://wordpress.org/support/update-php/).